# Java Flux Exception Handling?

Tags: java, stream, flux, parallelstream

Can someone please guide me as I am new to the flux and trying to understand how to handle this scenario?

**Issue:** I am getting readTimeout exception in one of the flux responses from `getResp()` method below and then all the prior successful responses are ignored and the exception error is returned.

Instead, I want to return all the successful responses I received prior to the exception.

```
public Flux<CustomObject1> getInfo(List<RequestObj> requestObjList) {
return requestObjList.stream()
       .parallel()
       .map(this::getResp)
       .reduce(Flux::Merge)
       .orElse(Flux.empty());
}

public Flux<CustomObject1> getResp(RequestObj requestObj){
// process the request and return ...        

}
```

Please let me know if this is not clear, happy to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle errors in `flatMap`

**Use `flatMapDelayError`** that will delay any error until all elements are processed

```
public Flux<CustomObject1> getInfo(List<RequestObj> requestObjList) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(requestObjList)
            .flatMapDelayError(this::getResp, Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, Queues.XS_BUFFER_SIZE)
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                // log error
                return Mono.empty();
            });
}
```

**Handle error for every element**

```
public Flux<CustomObject1> getInfo(List<RequestObj> requestObjList) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(requestObjList)
            .flatMap(request -> 
                    getResp(request)
                            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                                // log error
                                return Mono.empty();
                            })
            );
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for answering my question.

For now, this is how I handled...

public Flux<CustomObject1> getInfo(List<RequestObj> requestObjList) {
return requestObjList.stream()
       .parallel()
       .map(this::getResp)
       .reduce(Flux::Merge)
       .orElse(Flux.empty());
}

public Flux<CustomObject1> getResp(RequestObj requestObj){
// process the request and return ...        

}

Comment: from what I see `getResp` returns `Flux` and you can't use java streams to resolve publishers.  `.map(this::getResp)` will not execute  `getResp` because in reactive "nothing happens until you subscribe". You need to construct flow using Reactor API and use different operators such `flatMap` to resolve publishers. Check my examples for details.